# PIL not drawing using multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-multiprocessing

In trying to make a program to generate images of the mandelbrot set, I'm trying to speed up processing time by splitting an image into chunks to be worked using multiprocessing however it wont draw to the image in PIL. The data is being correctly processed i think, it's just not interacting with the global image.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
from mandelbrot import mandelbrot, MAX_ITER
import time
import threading
import multiprocessing
from numpy import floor
# Image size (pixels)
WIDTH = 150*2
HEIGHT = 150*2
t = time.time()


# End_Point = [-0.5,0]
# End_Zoom = 1.5
End_Point = [-4.556239E-2, -6.824076E-1]
End_Zoom = 4.167107E-5
End_Value = [End_Point[0]-End_Zoom, End_Point[0]+End_Zoom, -(End_Point[1])-End_Zoom, -(End_Point[1])+End_Zoom]


palette = []

im = Image.new('HSV', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), (0, 0, 0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)

def threadDraw(xPos, yPos,GridNumber):
    
    xStart = int(floor(xPos*WIDTH/GridNumber))
    xEnd = int(floor((xPos+1)*WIDTH/GridNumber))
    yStart = int(floor(yPos*HEIGHT/GridNumber))
    yEnd = int(floor((yPos+1)*HEIGHT/GridNumber))
    
    for x in range(xStart, xEnd):
        mapping[x] = []
        for y in range(yStart, yEnd):
            # Convert pixel coordinate to complex number
            c = complex(End_Value[0] + (x / WIDTH) * (End_Value[1] - End_Value[0]),
                        End_Value[2] + (y / HEIGHT) * (End_Value[3] - End_Value[2]))
            # Compute the number of iterations
            m = mandelbrot(c)
            # The color depends on the number of iterations
            hue = int(255 * m / MAX_ITER)
            saturation = 255
            value = 255 if m < MAX_ITER else 0
            # Plot the point 
            draw.point([x, y], (hue, saturation, value))
            #mapping[x].append([hue, saturation, value])
Division = 2
threads = []
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    for z in range(int(Division/2)):
            for l in range(int(Division/2)):
                threads.append(multiprocessing.Process(target=threadDraw, args=(z,l,Division/2)))
    starttime = time.time()
    for x in threads:    
        x.start()
    for x in threads:
        x.join()

    print('Time taken = {} seconds'.format(time.time() - starttime))
    drawImage()
    im = im.convert('RGB')
    im.show()
```

Comment: The important distinction here is between processes and threads. Neither are a straightforward fit here, but the difference has key implications.

Comment: I used the term "threads" for my variables admittedly because I was being lazy as originally I tried using threading but that didn't improve performance enough unsurprisingly so I thought multiprocessing would work better. The threading based version worked though.

Comment: Threads in python have a major limitation, the GIL. The library documentation will tell you whether it releases the GIL. If it does, you can use threads; if it doesn't (or doesn't say), threads will be ineffective (slower than single thread).

Comment: Processes are isolated; there are no globals. You'll have to pass the tiles back to the main process yourself and stitch them together.

Answer (score 0):

The important distinction here is between processes and threads. Neither are a straightforward fit here, but the difference has key implications.

Threads in python have a major limitation, the GIL. The library documentation will tell you whether it releases the GIL. If it does, you can use threads; if it doesn't (or doesn't say), threads will be ineffective (slower than single thread). Based on your comment, it looks like this library doesn't.

Processes are isolated; there are no globals. You'll have to pass the tiles back to the main process yourself, perhaps using a queue or files on disk, and stitch them together yourself.